# Is there iron in my hot water heater, and will running a softener clear it?

Tags: water-heater, water-softener

I'm on well water and there is a lot of iron in it, so I put in Culligan water softener outfit. Before I always got a lot of orange-red color water came out after regeneration; with this new softener it is good on the cold water side, but when you run hot water by itself it fills up a sink or bathtub with orange water.

Since it is only on the hot side it would have to be build up in water heater, right? For context, this is a sectional home that sat empty for quite a while before I bought it.

Will the new softener eventually clean the water tank out over time? Suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Try flushing the Hot water tank.

Comment: I have done that, and it seems ok for maybe 4 or 5 day then out of no where its back to doing it, im wondering if its built up inside water heater and as more soft water is added after regineration it is possibly breaking it down???

Comment: It could be.  Since you said it sat for quite awhile, it could be that the tank is well  lined with rusty sediment.  I believe there is something that can be added to a tank to help clean it, but my memory of exactly what is poor.  Perhaps google it.

Comment: th qustion might gt bttr answrs if writtin mor carfully use puntuation

Comment: Thanks for the help, RMDman

Comment: Is the water softener output piped into the hot water heater? Sounds to me like it might be plumbed in _after_ a Tee to the heater...